# How to disable gradient dithering in browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, filter, gradient, dithering

**Situation/Problem**

When making a SVG filter, I stumbled upon something strange. When converting the original CSS gradient to R, G or B color only (whichever channel has the highest value), I get dithering in the gradient.

**Question**

While this usually is a good thing for visual performance, it now messes up the calculations/masking in my SVG `<filter>`.

Is there a way to disable this dithering? Or to prevent it from occurring?

**Example**

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: sans-serif; }

.wheel {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #ff0, #0f0, #0ff, #00f, #f0f, #f00); */
    /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #f88, #ff8, #8f8, #8ff, #88f, #f8f, #f88); */
    /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #f44, #ff4, #4f4, #4ff, #44f, #f4f, #f44); */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffe0e0, #ffffe0, #e0ffe0, #e0ffff, #e0e0ff, #ffe0ff, #ffe0e0);
}

.very-light {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fffafa, #fffffa, #fafffa, #faffff, #fafaff, #fffaff, #fffafa);
}

.filter {
    filter: url(#max-channel);
    /* Does not change gradient dithering behaviour */
    /*transform: translateZ(0);*/
}

.expected {
    background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #f00 0%,
        #f00 calc((1/6) * 100%),
        #0f0 calc((1/6) * 100%),
        #0f0 calc((3/6) * 100%),
        #00f calc((3/6) * 100%),
        #00f calc((5/6) * 100%),
        #f00 calc((5/6) * 100%),
        #f00 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel">Original <code>linear-gradient()</code></div>
<div class="wheel filter"><code>linear-gradient()</code> with SVG filter applied</div>
<div class="wheel filter very-light">Even worse on very light gradient..!</div>
<div class="wheel expected">Expected result</div>

<svg
    version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="0" height="0"
>
    <filter id="max-channel" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    
        <feFlood flood-color="#ff0000" result="red" />
        <feFlood flood-color="#00ff00" result="green" />
        <feFlood flood-color="#0000ff" result="blue" />

        <!-- Separate channels -->
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="r-channel">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncR>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncG>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncB>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="g-channel">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncR>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncG>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncB>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="b-channel">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncR>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 0"></feFuncG>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncB>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        
        <!-- Red is max mask -->
        <feBlend mode="lighten" in="SourceGraphic" in2="red" result="r-lighten" />
        <feBlend mode="difference" in="SourceGraphic" in2="r-lighten" result="r-lighten-diff" />
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="r-lighten-diff" result="r-max-mask"
            values="0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  -255 0 0 0 1"
        />
        
        <!-- Green is max mask -->
        <feBlend mode="lighten" in="SourceGraphic" in2="green" result="g-lighten" />
        <feBlend mode="difference" in="SourceGraphic" in2="g-lighten" result="g-lighten-diff" />
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="g-lighten-diff" result="g-max-beforemask"
            values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 0 0 0  0 -255 0 0 1"
        />
        <feComposite operator="out" in="g-max-beforemask" in2="r-max-mask" result="g-max-mask" />
        
        <!-- Blue is max mask -->
        <feBlend mode="lighten" in="SourceGraphic" in2="blue" result="b-lighten" />
        <feBlend mode="difference" in="SourceGraphic" in2="b-lighten" result="b-lighten-diff" />
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="b-lighten-diff" result="b-max-beforemask"
            values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 1  0 0 -255 0 1"
        />
        <feComposite operator="out" in="b-max-beforemask" in2="r-max-mask" result="b-max-beforemask2" />
        <feComposite operator="out" in="b-max-beforemask2" in2="g-max-mask" result="b-max-mask" />

        <feMerge>
            <!-- <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" /> -->
            <!-- <feMergeNode in="r-channel" /> -->
            <!-- <feMergeNode in="r-lighten-diff" /> -->
            <feMergeNode in="b-max-mask" />
            <feMergeNode in="g-max-mask" />
            <feMergeNode in="r-max-mask" />
        </feMerge>

    </filter>
</svg>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Here you have two color wheel bars. The bottom one has the SVG filter applied to it. The filter should show full red on colors where red is the (shared) highest channel, then green, then blue. Ideally it would show 4 blocks that are, if added, have almost equal width. ***But*** as you can see, the dithering messes this up, and thus the blocks are dithered areas. For very light color gradients it's even worse.

Platform: Windows 10 - Browser: Chrome version 93.0.4577.82 (64-bit) (But happens in Edge as well.)

***Notes:***

- I tried adding `transform: translateZ(0)` to the element to force it to hardware acceleration, but it makes no difference.
- I found a [thread on adding dithering to Chromium browsers](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627771), but not sure if this has happened.

**Update**

As suggested by Michael, I tried using a blur before applying the rest of the filter. By adding `<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" in="SourceGraphic" result="blurred-img" />` to the filter and using `blurred-img` instead of `SourceGraphic`. But as you can see from the screenshot below, it does not disable the dithering or deals with the 'troubled' pixels.

The trouble there is that they probably have a very small positive value because of calculations, but so small that dithering kicks in instead of assuming 0 opacity.

**With blur of 1 px**

[image]

**FYI**

So although it does not really have something to do with the question, I will explain the use case a bit.

In short, this filter will be used to effect a specific range of colors of the original image based on their hue value.

In order to do that, this filter above makes a mask that will ‘select’ a certain range of colors. The result can then be put through the actual effect and then pasted over the original image. For example all red tones in an image get hue rotated.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: On Chrome 93/Win10 (64 bit) - I am unable to reproduce the problems you're showing with the normal gradient. On my machine it produces the expected result. (The very light gradient does show issues)

Comment: Since the filter code is a bit long, used the JS Fiddle. But I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to undo dithering is to add a small blur to the source graphic and use that result instead of the SourceGraphic as input.

Comment: Adding a small blur does not remove the dithering unfortunately ([see here](https://jsfiddle.net/PhilQ/nr2m9sdp/4/)). It just makes the area of a certain dithering wider and more 'blocky'. The cause of the dithering is probably because of floating numbers and the browser or graphics engine trying to account for that 'less than 1' value of opacity and fixes that by using dithering.

Comment: stdDeviation=3 gets rid of the dithering on Chrome/Win64? YMMV apparently

Comment: I haven't tried `3`, but then the image you're applying the filter to will be blurred. I would like to keep the original sharpness of the image. (This filter is a preparation the be able to apply effects on certain color ranges based on hue. So it's important it can mark the r/g/b accurately without dithering or blurring the image.)

Comment: I think you might want to explain the use case more fully with a full example so people can figure out how to solve your problem